# Using the "curiously recurring template pattern" in a multi-file program

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I'm a pretty novice (C++) programmer and have just discovered the CRTP for keeping count of objects belonging to a particular class.

I implemented it like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Counter
{
    Counter();
    virtual ~Counter();

    static int count;
};

template <typename T> Counter<T>::Counter()
{
    ++count;
}

template <typename T> Counter<T>::~Counter()
{
    --count;
}

template <typename T> int Counter<T>::count(0);
```

which seems to work.  However, it doesn't seem to like inheriting from it in a separate header file, where I declared this:

```
class Infector : public Counter<Infector>
{
    public:
        Infector();
        virtual ~Infector();

        virtual void infect(Infectee target);
        virtual void replicate() = 0;
        virtual void transmit() = 0;

    protected:
    private:
};
```

Everything compiles just fine without the inheritance, so I'm fairly sure it can't see the declaration and definition of the template.  Anybody have any suggestions as to where I might be going wrong and what I can do about it?  Should I be using extern before my Infector definition to let the compiler know about the Counter template or something like that?

Cheers,

Kyle

Comment: Did you remember to include the file that defines Counter (i.e. #include "Counter.h")?

Comment: You will have to post the error messages you're seeing. We aren't psychic here.

Comment: Also, what compiler are you using? CRTP can seriously upset some older compilers. If you're still using GCC 3.4 (MinGW only finally took the GCC 4 plunge relatively recently, with version 4.4) you may have problems because of that. I could be mixing versions, but I think I had infinite loops in the compiler doing similar template trickery in MinGW GCC 3.4.5

Comment: @sbi, sorry for not including the specific error messages, they were basically along the lines of "expected keyword template before token '<'" and similar syntax errors because it couldn't interpret the declaration of the Infector class.

Comment: That doesn't sound like it would fit to what Chris wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed you specifically mentioned declarations and definitions.
Do you have them in separate files?

If so, templates are header only creatures. You'll need to put your definitions in the header file.

Comment: Ahh, awesome.  Thanks a lot.  I'll move the template to a header file, I had it as a linked object file, which I guess isn't sufficient for the rest of the code to be aware of it.  Cheers.